# AFNetworking upload a file referenced with a forKey

Tags: ios, url, post, file-upload, afnetworking

I need to send to a web server some informations that the user inserts in my app

I was using ASIHTTPRequest but i'm having some problems with iOS 5, so I decided to move to AFNetworking

this is the code I've written so far...

```
AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://theserver.com/upload.php"]];
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters setObject:[fieldName text] forKey:@"name"];
[parameters setObject:[fieldSurname text] forKey:@"surname"];
```

Now I need to add a NSData object containing an image, and it should be referenced by forKey:@"attachment"

what should I write? with ASIHTTPRequest I was using

```
[request setData:myNSData withFileName:@"image.jpg" andContentType:@"application/octet-stream" forKey:@"attachment"];
```

but with AFNetworking I don't know what should I write, and the examples doesn't help me

thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use "multipartFormRequestWithMethod" - eg:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPClient sharedClient] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
  [formData appendPartWithFileData:data mimeType:@"image/jpeg" name:@"attachment"];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks!! But instead of "parameters=nil" I should pass to it my "NSMutableDictionary *parameters", right?

And when I declare "AFHTTPClient *client"... I need to insert the entire path or just "http://theserver.com" ?

Comment: Yes, you can pass in your parameters. When you create the AFHTTPClient, just pass the base url - ie. http://theserver.com/ (with the http://, which stackoverflow seems intent on hiding)

Comment: is data a UIImage? does it matter?

Comment: @mkral data is an NSData. To convert a UIImage to an NSData look at UIImageJPEGRepresentation().